# Setup Project in Visual Studio 2010 : Unknown Publisher?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, installation, setup-project

I have a VS 2008 Setup Project created.  I am trying to install this on a Windows 7 machine as a Standard User.  I am getting a warning during install about an unknown publisher.  I have used makecert to create a certificate, then converted it to a password pfx file.  I have digitally signed the msi and setup.exe with the pfx file.  When I go into the file properties, I can see the digital certificate attached.  On the Windows 7 machine, I imported the pfx file to "Trusted Publishers".  What do I need to do to get rid of the warning?  I can't have the admin user and password required to install the app.  I can't change the UAC settings.  I need to make the change to the certificate / setup files to get this to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Makecert creates certificates only for testing purposes. To sign your installer you need a real certificate purchased from an official authority. You can try purchasing one from Verisign or Comodo.

Windows UAC recognizes only real certificates.